# Sql joining from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with same structure.
I want to display non matching records from both tables based on id, But they should be displayed in same row like below image:

[image]

Comment: can you share table detail?

Comment: Please provide the structure of the two tables.

Comment: You probably want to use `INNER JOIN` keyword 
ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Y have mentioned like  _`display non matching records from both tables based on id`_, then how this output is possible? please clarify.

Comment: If you want help, it's more motivating for us if you show some effort. A picture of a scribbled note is *not* effort.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little to go on, but maybe something like:

```
SELECT table1.Id, table1.Name [, table1.etc]
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.Id = table2.id
WHERE table2.id is null
UNION 
SELECT table2.Id, table2.Name [, table2.etc]
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1
  ON table2.Id = table1.id
WHERE table1.id is null
```